What type of technical roles include client contact?
I want to get out of tech support and land in a more established corporation helping clients solve problems and helping sales teams close deals. At this point in my life I have had 15 years of experience in various IT/sales positions but I don't know where to apply or what jobs do what.
I was a field tech/sysadmin for 5 years at a non profit that had no technology structure or interest in building out that team
Then I moved on to retail sales at Best Buy, I loved interacting with customers and making the sale, but the career path was long, and too cliquey so I left for an inside sales position at an ecommerce website that sold technology hardware. I really liked this job a lot except for the micromanaging and lack of career advancement from the call center.
Then I found out about government contracts and that you make pretty good money doing those. I took two gov jobs after COVID. One at a prison and one at a command center for a 3 letter agency. I once again loved interacting with my coworkers and staff at the prison, and hated the job at the command center. Plus it was night shift and working with unfriendly coworkers, I didn't last long.
Now I am back in a client facing role as a linux engineer. Once again I love interacting with clients and coworkers but there are limited opportunities at this company being that it is small.
I have a lot of little exp in little things and seemingly no structure
Advice I have received is to start to pivot into sales or professional services. I have no idea what these sorts of career paths look like as I believe sales engineering and Customer success roles are pretty unique fields that probably require experience I don't have.
Does anyone have any advice of what I should do here?

I don't have the slightest clue what you're asking. Maybe try to rewrite your question with a more focused question that we can address.

It sounds like you've made a cardinal mistake in sales. You've gone into a conversation not being clear to anyone what you want out of it. Amongst the muddle it sounds like you just want the jobs you already have, but stable with more money, and with a better social scene.

You do not understand that these have no meaning. You deal with a bunch of nothing. In general, if you do not understand, what your direct co-worker is doing, odds is above 80% that he does nothing. But keep silent, it can have unthinkably many reasons for that (f.e.: a customer (can be also government) wants to deal with a company where such a guy, with this role, sits in this job) and you do not want to interfere with these reasons.

It Sounds like what you are looking for is either some form of Pre-sales architect role, a solutions architect role or some form of Consulting role.
Now - we cant tell you what you should do - but reading the question - the question (as I understood it) is:

You want to be in a customer facing, senior technical role.
You still want to be hands-on
You want to find solutions for your clients problems

I think a pre-sales role is probably what you would want to look at. It has all the customer-facing elements that you want, it has the solution design that you want - and for someone with as much technical experience as you, it should be a good fit.
